# Fail to test the rendered output after a redirect from a DELETE route - Mojolicious

Tags: perl, redirect, testing, mojolicious, test-more

I currently expand my test suite to increase the test coverage. I want to test my controller and the html output that it renders, but I found a problem in using *delete* methods. Let me explain it in an example.

I have a route:

```
$r->delete('/backups/:id')
  ->to('backup#delete_backup')
  ->name('backup_delete');
```

that points to the following function in the `backup` controller:

```
sub delete_backup {
    my $self       = shift;
    my $id         = $self->param('id');


    if ( something ) {
        $self->flash( msg => "Backup id $id deleted!" );
    }
    else{
        $self->flash( msg => "Cannot delete, backup id $id not found!" );   
    }
    $self->redirect_to($self->url_for('backup_index'));
}
```

where the method that handles the route `backup_index` just displays the `$msg` and shows few other irrelevant data.

Next, I want to test this method, so I write a test:

```
$t_logged_in->ua->max_redirects(3);
my $page = $t_logged_in->app->url_for( 'backup_delete', id => $backup_id );
$t_logged_in->delete_ok($page)
            ->status_isnt( 404, "Checking: 404 $page" )
            ->status_isnt( 500, "Checking: 500 $page" );
```

The test is passed. But now, I want to check if the text is correct on the web page that is shown after redirecting. So I do the following:

```
$t_logged_in->ua->max_redirects(3);
my $page = $t_logged_in->app->url_for( 'backup_delete', id => $backup_id );
$t_logged_in->delete_ok($page)
            ->status_isnt( 404, "Checking: 404 $page" )
            ->status_isnt( 500, "Checking: 500 $page" )
            ->content_unlike(qr/Cannot delete,/i)
            ->content_like(qr/deleted/i);
```

The test fails. It fails because the content is empty, so the matching is done as there were:

```
'' =~ /deleted/i;
'' !~ /Cannot delete,/i;
```

and this is of course false in both cases. Of course, in the browser, the redirects work perfectly and I see everything as designed in the test. I can change the method to `POST` or `GET` but I wanted to make the routing properly in the way an API would be designed.

**Question**: how to design the test such that the content can be matched after the redirect?

For those who want to dig deeper, I give links to Github.

- [Routing definition line 303](https://github.com/vikin91/BibSpace/blob/dev/lib/BibSpace.pm)
- [Controller Backup function delete_backup line 135](https://github.com/vikin91/BibSpace/blob/dev/lib/BibSpace/Controller/Backup.pm)
- [Functional Test of Backup Controller line 53](https://github.com/vikin91/BibSpace/blob/dev/t/001_frontend_basic_backup.t)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry no one answered this yet. I used to try to keep a closer eye on stack overflow but I got lazy :-P. This is a very interesting question.

Standard redirects (301/302) use the same verb as the original request UNLESS the original request was a `POST` Interestingly, this behavior was not really intended. A redirect is supposed to use the same request method as the original, but the `POST`->`GET` redirect is so commonly intended that most browsers added this behavior even though it was against the original definition. However some people really wanted a `POST` to remain a `POST` and now it depended on the implementation. In fact this got so bad that HTTP added response statuses 307/308 which always redirects as the same http verb (ie `POST` -> `POST`), even thought that was already the official behavior of the old ones but that ship had sailed. This means that `POST`->`GET`, but `DELETE`->`DELETE` is the defacto behavior of the 301/302.

This can be demonstrated in the following one liner (`$_` in these one-liners is the controller):

```
perl -Mojo -E 'del "/delete" => sub { $_->redirect_to("/") }; any "/" => { inline => q[I got a <%= $c->req->method %>] }; app->start' get -r -v -M DELETE /delete

DELETE /delete HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:62690
Accept-Encoding: gzip
User-Agent: Mojolicious (Perl)
Content-Length: 0

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Sun, 18 Sep 2016 03:25:58 GMT
Server: Mojolicious (Perl)
Location: /
Content-Length: 0

DELETE / HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 0
User-Agent: Mojolicious (Perl)
Host: 127.0.0.1:62690
Accept-Encoding: gzip

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 5
Date: Sun, 18 Sep 2016 03:25:58 GMT
Server: Mojolicious (Perl)

I got a DELETE
```

You can see that since my `/` route handles all methods we get a response, however the request was a `DELETE`. I see that in your app, you redirect to another named route whose url also handles `DELETE`. This is a source of your confusion as you are actually ending up there in your tests. Your redirect is effectively `DELETE /backups/<<id>>` -> `DELETE /backups`, if I'm reading your code correctly.

Now as opposed to the people who wanted to keep `POST` as `POST`, what you want here is the opposite, you want to redirect from `DELETE` to `GET` because you are trying to show a response that is not the original resource. This is the defined behavior of the little-known 303 response in which any request method is redirected to a `GET`. Indeed this is what early browsers *should* have insisted on rather than breaking the 302.

In the following example I modify the response code to 303 explicitly.

```
$ perl -Mojo -E 'del "/delete" => sub { $_->res->code(303); $_->redirect_to("/") }; any "/" => { inline => q[I got a <%= $c->req->method %>] }; app->start' get -r -v -M DELETE /delete
DELETE /delete HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mojolicious (Perl)
Host: 127.0.0.1:62716
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 0

HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
Location: /
Content-Length: 0
Server: Mojolicious (Perl)
Date: Sun, 18 Sep 2016 03:27:19 GMT

DELETE / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mojolicious (Perl)
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 0
Host: 127.0.0.1:62716

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Server: Mojolicious (Perl)
Content-Length: 5
Date: Sun, 18 Sep 2016 03:27:19 GMT

I got a DELETE
```

But whoops, that's still a `DELETE`! That's because there was a [bug](https://github.com/kraih/mojo/issues/999) in Mojo::UserAgent so that it didn't handle 303s correctly. I'd suggest you still make the change to your code since browsers seem to handle 303s correctly. However since Mojo::UserAgent powers Test::Mojo, your tests can't test that behavior yet. Once [fixed](https://github.com/kraih/mojo/issues/1000) you will see it work correctly, as my example does in my local branch:

```
$ perl -Ilib -Mojo -E 'del "/delete" => sub { $_->res->code(303); $_->redirect_to("/") }; any "/" => { inline => q[I got a <%= $c->req->method %>] }; app->start' get -r -v -M DELETE /delete
DELETE /delete HTTP/1.1                                                                  
Content-Length: 0                                                                        
User-Agent: Mojolicious (Perl)                                                           
Host: 127.0.0.1:64924                                                                    
Accept-Encoding: gzip                                                                    

HTTP/1.1 303 See Other                                                                   
Date: Sun, 18 Sep 2016 04:59:37 GMT                                                      
Location: /                                                                              
Server: Mojolicious (Perl)                                                               
Content-Length: 0                                                                        

GET / HTTP/1.1                                                                           
Content-Length: 0                                                                        
User-Agent: Mojolicious (Perl)                                                           
Host: 127.0.0.1:64924                                                                    
Accept-Encoding: gzip                                                                    

HTTP/1.1 200 OK                                                                          
Date: Sun, 18 Sep 2016 04:59:37 GMT                                                      
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8                                                    
Server: Mojolicious (Perl)                                                               
Content-Length: 12                                                                       

I got a GET
```

To see more about redirect response types see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection